# IF/ELSE Statement doesn't work with int.parse?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

I really don't get it. "twoMark" and "twoTente" are null so I made an If/else statement to convert them into 0 if they are indeed null or if not, just int.parse the value... but the code just IGNORE the IF and go straight to the else even tho the value is null so it is supposed to stop after it.

SO i get this error:  Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1).

Because for my understanding he is trying to do the "twoMark = int.parse(twoMark ??= '0');" instead of stopping at "twoMark = int.parse(twoMark == null ? twoMark : '0');"

```
if(twoMark == null){
    print("FGM EST NULLE");
    twoMark = int.parse(twoMark == null ? twoMark : '0');
  }else{
    print(" FGM N'EST PAS NULLE");
    twoMark = int.parse(twoMark ??= '0');

  }
```

my console is printing the second print even tho "twoMark" IS NULL.

----------- FULL CODE ---------

```
avePicture(pathing, idTeamPlayer, fPlayerName, lPlayerName, phonePlayer, age,
    taille, jerNumb, position, fgm, fga, context) async {
  SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;
  final statAccess = DatabaseModel();
  int? idPlayer = sp.getInt("idPlayer");
  idTeamPlayer = sp.getInt("idTeam");
  phonePlayer = phonePlayer.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9]'), '');
  fPlayerName = fPlayerName.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z]'), '');
  lPlayerName = lPlayerName.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z]'), '');
  var twoTente = fga;
  var twoMark = fgm;
  if(jerNumb != null){
    jerNumb = jerNumb.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9]'), '');
  }
  twoMark ??= '0';
  final intTwooMark = int.parse(twoMark);
  print("THE TWO $intTwooMark");
```

Comment: `int.parse(twoMark == null ? twoMark : '0')` is backwards.  If `twoMark` is `null`, you're calling `int.parse(null)`.  The `twoMark == null` check is redundant anyway since you already checked it in the outer `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int.parse` expect a string inside it, Use `int.tryParse` to avoid getting exception.

use

```dart
 final intTwooMark = int.tryParse(twoMark.toString())??0;
```

You can do

```dart
twoMark = int.tryParse("${twoMark == null ? twoMark : '0'}")??0; // not necessarily have to be like this, just an example
```

Or

```dart
twoMark = int.tryParse(twoMark.toString())??0;
```

Or just, it will assign right part if the left is null

```dart
twoMark??=0;
```

```dart
if (twoMark == null) {
  print("FGM EST NULLE");
  twoMark ??= 0; //or just  twoMark = 0;
} else {
  print(" FGM N'EST PAS NULLE");
  twoMark = twoMark; // no need
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `int.tryParse` to avoid  numeric string exception

Comment: Nothing works, I have even tried to do "if (twoTente == null){print("hello"}; but it doesn't even print it !!

Comment: Can you include full snippet

Comment: Try `final intTwooMark = int.tryParse(twoMark.toString())??0;` and it is better to avoid using `var` to have more control over code writing

Comment: your "tryParse" worked. thanks man, I was stuck for hours.

Comment: Then I suspect the issue was the string wasn't a numeric value. Always try using [`.tryParse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/tryParse.html)

Comment: Yes you are probably right. I didn't know "tryParse" existed ^^'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```dart
twoMark ??= '0';
final intTwoMark = int.parse(twoMark);
```

You'll obtain a more readable dart-ish code with just two simple lines of code.

EDIT. If you aren't sure your string is actually convertible, use `tryParse` and / or use a `try catch` block and decide whatever you want to do with it, e.g. assign `null` to `intToMark`

Comment: It doesn't work :  Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Comment: @zsupraz Then `twoMark` is a non-`null` `String` that does not represent a number.  Either: A. Fix the input. B. `catch` the `FormatException`. C. Use `int.tryParse` and handle it returning `null`.

Comment: yeah the "tryParse" worked for me, I didn't know it exist I am new to flutter. Thx for the help !